# function onOpen() is not running

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

My function includes adding a menu and toast to the document. I have verified that the trigger (onOpen) is set as well. It only works when a user goes into Tools, Script Manager, Run. We have too many users with too many backgrounds to expect then to know how to do this. Why isn't it working? (Using Chrome)

```
function onOpen()
{
  var menus = [{name: "Advance in Workflow", functionName:"sendEmail"}];

     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Auto Advance FG Workflow", menus);

  //sheet.toast(Notify/Remind users);
   sheet.toast("While you are here we kindly ask that you do not add, modify or remove     any columns.","Welcome - " + username,8);
 }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Is this your actual code?  Where does the 'username' come from?

Comment: This is the actual code. The script has defined var's throughout. Prior to the function onOpen, user name is defined as follows: var username = Session.getActiveUser().getUsername();

Comment: No. The onOpen function is still not running on open. Users are forced to go into Tools>Script Manager> select it, and click Run in order to get the menu and toast.

Comment: Have you tried to add an installable trigger on the same onOpen() function... usually it does solve the issue.

Comment: Serge, the onInstall function is acting the same as the onOpen. With the trigger set to run the script when the document opens, it still will not show the menu item unless you run it through Tools>Script Manager.

Comment: installableOnOpen function also behaved in the same manner. Is it possible there is something wrong with the settings of the document that are preventing the script to running without the use of script manager? If I set the trigger to run on Edit, it works, but not all users make edits before they need the menu option.

Comment: Simple triggers (such as the default onOpen() function) cannot determine the current user. An installable trigger should be able to though but must be installed by each user for which the scripts needs to run.

Comment: From https://script.google.com/home/executions I see a permissions error, can you details a little more if you find any error?

Answer (score 41):

I was having the same issue.

I realized, sometimes Google create some kind of cache of the scripts (I'm used to have a "test" script and I usually alter it's content, and, sometimes, the script runs as if I didn't).

So, what I did that solved the onOpen() not working was changing the function name and ading a trigger manually.

> [image: Go to "Resources -> Current script's triggers…"]
>
> Go to "Resources -> Current script's triggers…"
>
> [image: Choose the function to run on open]
>
> Choose the function to run on open

It worked like a charm here!

Updated Location Information:
[image: from tool bar]
or
[image: from menu bar]

Then

[image: trigger select]

Comment: I tried my own trick and it didn't solve the problem. It only worked after I remove all variables that were not inside functions... I don't know, why, but it solved the problem.

Answer (score 15):

This is an old post but I just had this problem and find out why it was not working correctly in my case:
I had, at the top of my script file a variable that required some authorisations and that prevented the script to correctly run. I saw that OP called `var username = Session.getActiveUser().getUsername();` (that requires authorisations, and it's may be the cause).

eg:
this code won't work:

```
function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu("Exportation")
  .addItem("Lancer l'exportation", "exportationMenu")
  .addToUi();
}
var stConsCons= SpreadsheetApp.openById(sgcid).getSheetByName("Consultant");
```

but this one will work:

```
function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu("Exportation")
  .addItem("Lancer l'exportation", "exportationMenu")
  .addToUi();
}

function whatever(){
  var stConsCons= SpreadsheetApp.openById(sgcid).getSheetByName("Consultant");
...}
```

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that you need to add the `onOpen(e)` function to Triggers!

[image: image description here]

Comment: this solved the problem in my case

Answer (score 5):

In my case, onOpen wasn't working because I had a variable, outside of a function, opening a sheet with `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` rather than `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`. I guess onOpen doesn't work with `openById()` even if the sheet you are opening is bound to the script. `onOpen()` won't work with this kind of a variable outside of a function:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1b_PQD...").getSheetByName("demos")
```

If your script is bound to the sheet, you can solve this problem by using the `getActiveSpreadsheet()` function. Otherwise, you can solve it by putting your `openById()` call into a function.

Answer (score 2):

In my case there was a reference error, that while did not stop the script entirely, it did stop the menu from appearing.

I was only able to detect that error after I run a debug on the script.

[image: Google script debug option]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem may be that "sheet" isn't defined, which is why the toast is failing.

Comment: The sheet is defined prior to the function: var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); Does it need to be within the function? Toast failing is not quite as important as the menu not appearing automatically...

Answer (score 0):

[Simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) silently fail if they lack permission.  I ran into this with an `onOpen()` in a script that initialized [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) objects of non-bound files.  I moved all File object instantiation to menu functions that do have permission.

In other words, this will not work

```
function onOpen(e) {
   ...
   let file = DriveApp.getFileById(nonBoundFileId);
   ...
}
```

but this will work

```
function menuFunction() {
   ...
   let file = DriveApp.getFileById(nonBoundFileId);
   ...
}
```

because menuFunction can be given permission(s) that simple triggers lack.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question, but for any one finding this now, I may have a solution. The onOpen function often runs with the authorization mode none instead of limited when being used as an event trigger. This may cause errors in things that are related to the specific file or user data. For example:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActivePresentation(); //Will error out if permissions are not set to limited.
SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); //This will always run even if the AuthMode is set to NONE
}
```

Additionally it is worth noting that if you have any variable used or initialized before onOpen(e), basically any global variables that access sensitive info fail if the AuthMode is set to NONE.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActivePresentation(); //bad
```

```
var ss;
...
function init() {
 ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActivePresentation(); //good because now that the function is already run we should have full permissions
}
```