# Trigger function onOpen stopped working in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm very new to this and hoping someone can help me. This script worked last week:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  // Replace ID & Last Name fields with generic information on open.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange('D8:D8').setValue("000000000");  
  ss.getRange('F8:F8').setValue("Brown");  
}
```

It worked fine last week, but when I opened it this morning, it just opens with D8 & F8 populated by whatever was last there. I tried closing all of my other accounts and restarting Chrome in case it was the "multiple accounts" bug. No dice.

When I run or debug the function, it causes no errors.

Removing the

```
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
```

line didn't do anything (tried that on a longshot because there's only one sheet).

D8 and F8 are the only fields I've left open for users to edit. They populate a hidden cell that concatenates the two fields as a key to pull data from another spreadsheet to which users have no direct access. Access for this sheet to pull data from that one has been authorized.

I mention this because I've spent most of today looking for a solution, and all I can find is some mention of permissions, which I've granted.

I REALLY hope someone can help. It went through testing last week and it worked. I'm supposed to present it TOMORROW.

Please help!

Comment: Is your question that the script is not replacing D8 and F8 with the values there in the script you have posted?

Comment: Check your error logs on Stackdriver. Note that triggers don't run when opened in anonymous / view-only modes.

Comment: Hi Jonathan,

Yes-sorry if that wasn't clear. Last week it was replacing the data in D8 & F8 with the "000000000" and "Brown" and now it does nothing.

Comment: Hi tehhowch, Thanks for your reply. I've only opened it from test accounts to which I've granted editor access. *looks for error logs* Ehhhh...It doesn't appear that I have access to stackdriver logs.

Comment: Okay...log says "You do not have permission to perform that action.
onOpen (Code:25)"

Comment: I apparently need an "oauthscope" in my manifest structure...maybe

Comment: I've tried updating the manifest, to no avail.

Comment: @Hope Set up a installable trigger(edit>triggers), so that the function  runs under your authority onOpen(Also Rename the function to something else).

Comment: @I'-'I  Thanks for the reply. I tried renaming and adding the installable trigger. Still no love.

Comment: @Jonathan, Yes-sorry if that wasn't clear. Last week it was replacing the data in D8 & F8 with the "000000000" and "Brown" and now it does nothing.

Comment: @tehhowch, Thanks for your reply. I've only opened it from test accounts to which I've granted editor access. 

log says "You do not have permission to perform that action. onOpen (Code:25)"
I've tried updating the manifest, to no avail.

Comment: @I'-'I It wasn't generating an error-BUT IT'S NOW WORKING!  I deleted all other code & typed it again. I'd cleaned it up last night and added three rows, so that's changed.  

Maybe a combination of all the things?  

I think the installable trigger was the key, though. THANK YOU!  

This code worked:

Comment: function Replace(e) {  

  // Replace ID & Last Name fields with generic information.  

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  

  ss.getRange('D11:D11').setValue("000000000");    

  ss.getRange('F11:F11').setValue("Brown");    

}

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. I tried using Ctrl+k and also tried 2 spaces, but it's still coming out like this.

Comment: Great..Consider accepting the same solution posted by another member below.

Comment: solution already given here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337599/function-onopen-is-not-running

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this would work for you, but you could try it - Instead of using the onOpen function, try renaming your function, and setting it up as an installable trigger, that triggers each time the spreadsheet opens.

rename function onOpen to function someOtherName, then
Edit --> Current Project's Triggers --> Click here to add one now -->

Change the name to your new function name, change the events from 'time-driven' to 'from spreadsheet', and the trigger to 'on open'.

HTH

Comment: Thanks! That's what I went with. (see comments). It works, but not every time. It seems to require some time in between "opens," even though it is set to trigger with an open, not time variable. As long as it doesn't reacquire the information from the source spreadsheet, it should be fine. It's just not "neat."