# onOpen Menu not working when variables are outside function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My onOpen function correctly creates menu items if I use a script with just this function. But whenever I add the three constants after it, the menu does not appear upon opening the spreadsheet.

Works:

```
function onOpen(e){
// This line calls the SpreadsheetApp and gets its UI   
// Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
// These lines create the menu items and 
// tie them to functions we will write in Apps Script
  ui.createMenu("Run Scripts")
      .addItem("1. Import CSV Data", "importCSV")
      .addItem("2. Copy Down Processing Formulas", "appendCSVrows")
      .addItem("3. Process CSV Data", "processCSVData")
      .addItem("4. Upload", "upload")
      .addItem("5. Create Lead Sheet", "upload")
      .addToUi();
}
```

Doesn't work:

```
function onOpen(e){
// This line calls the SpreadsheetApp and gets its UI   
// Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
// These lines create the menu items and 
// tie them to functions we will write in Apps Script
  ui.createMenu("Run Scripts")
      .addItem("1. Import CSV Data", "importCSV")
      .addItem("2. Copy Down Processing Formulas", "appendCSVrows")
      .addItem("3. Process CSV Data", "processCSVData")
      .addItem("4. Upload", "upload")
      .addItem("5. Create Lead Sheet", "upload")
      .addToUi();
}


const csvSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CSV Data");
const processingSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Processing Sheet");
const uploadSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Upload Sheet");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that for some reason having variables outside a function won't work. So you need to have all variables contained within functions and the simple trigger onOpen() should work.
I found the above explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59227643/10312679

But I didn't want to rewrite my script so I found this solution that overrides the above problem. You just manually create an onOpen trigger under the trigger settings of the project/script as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13527430/10312679